# How to open Ubuntu files in an interface friendly editor from Windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, text-editor

I am using Ubuntu app inside the Windows 10. I am writing some programs inside the Ubuntu OS, able to edit the files through the Vim editor from terminal interface.

I am wondering if there is a way to open the files in Ubuntu through the interface friendly editor like Vs-code? It will be super cool. Like for example opening Vs-code in Windows and somehow configure it to access directories inside the Ubuntu system.

Let me know if you need any more specific details. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  In Windows VSCode, install either:

- The "Remote - WSL" extension
- The "Remote Development" extension pack, which includes the "Remote - WSL" extension, along with similar features for Docker and SSH.

Once you've installed that, from inside your Ubuntu instance, you can:

```
code .
```

... to open the current directory in VSCode.  Or:

```
code filename
```

to open a particular file.

You can also start from inside VSCode, and open any of your WSL instances to browse the directory structure.  You'll find an icon for this that looks like "><" stacked together at the bottom left of the status-bar.  That's the "Open a Remote Window" tool.

Alternatively, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type "remote" to get a list of the features available from those extensions.

This extension creates a server running inside Ubuntu with which VSCode communicates.  It not only allows editing, but also connecting to debuggers in Ubuntu, etc.